# What about SoftwareBusinessOverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, business

I'm running a small one person shareware company. So i'm interested a lot in questions around the software industries business aspects. A lot of them are so specialized to software that i thought they belong somewhere here but stackoverflow and serverfault are closing them regularly?

Do you see a need for this?

At the moment the only forum i know is the paid newsgroup from the "Association of shareware professionals - ASP".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't this what the two Stack Exchange startup oriented sites are for?

http://answers.onstartups.com/
http://startups.com/

Comment: Coming back 10 years later. One link is gone, another is a subscription scam and i still haven't found any other resource. Luckily i made it myself with a lot of expensive errors i had to learn.

Comment: cool @Lothar what'd you make?